# Cannot get unity hololens project to work

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015, hololens, hololens-emulator

I'm trying to get a project to work that i downloaded [this link over here](https://github.com/Esri/hololens-terrain-viewer), from github.

I've followed all the (configuration) steps in the install guide and i am using the exact versions of the software as described in the guide.

The problem seems to be that some references to the Windows namespace do not work.
I've tried adding it but i can't get it done in the usual way.

The error messages i get when building in unity:
[image]

When i open the project in visual studio 2015 update 3 (after building it in unity):
[image]

It seems that the option to simply add the reference in visual studio is not present in this kind of project.

I think this shouldn't be to hard to resolve but i lack the skills and experience as i usually develop windows apps solely in visual studio.

***EDIT***

These are the configurations I used:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: in Unity are you on the correct target (UWP)?

Comment: @derHugo I added some screenshots that show my configuration settings. I am using Windows Universal 10 (as described in the guide i used).

Comment: which Version of the MixedRealityToolkit / HoloToolkit are you using? I can see you use Unity 5.5. which is quite old ... are you sure the MR-Toolkit version is for that Unity version? Any chance to move to a newer one?

Comment: @derHugo I downloaded everything the guide told me to use. Please see the link i posted at the beginning of my question. The version of the HoloToolkit that came with the project when i downloaded it is (according to the guide) compatible with the version of Unity i'm using

Comment: For the scripting backend option in the build settings try changing to IL2CPP

Comment: @slaphshot33324 I tried it and it didn't work either.. The guide also tells me to check the "Unity C# Projects" setting in the build settings. When changing to IL2CPP this option becomes unavailable. But still, i tried it, it didn't work unfortunately...

Comment: I added the unity editor log. i cleaned my log first before i started up the project in unity.

Comment: Can you search the solution for IAsyncAction to make sure it (or any of the others it says you are missing) truly does exist.

Comment: I'd try updating to unity 2017 LTS and ensuring your platform is Universal Windows Platform instead of Windows Store. That should nix the errors involving not being able to find the windows namespace and you should be able to build correctly.  

Side note, if there are errors then it won't build anything and there should be nothing to open via visual studio.  So don't worry about visual studio until you get a successful build in unity.

Answer (score 0):

> i open the project in visual studio 2015 update 3

You should use Visual Studio 2017 with the latest Win10 SDKs.